# ListView in android not saving ratingBar stars

Tags: android, listview, ratingbar

I have a problem with a listView that I made that has a ratingbar and a texview element.Its a very simple program that is meant to displays the list and stores the value of the stars that the user enters into the ratingBar. Unfortunately for some reason when I scroll up and down the rows that go out of the screen, when scrolled back in have their stars changed back to their intial value.The code is below. If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks.

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener {

private String[] textList = {"Pikachu","Raichu","Raticate","Ratata","Absol","Abra","Kadabra","Pidgey","Mime","Meowth","Mew","Squirtle","Blastoise","Goop","Kilobyte","Armada"};
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for(int i=0; i<textList.length; i++)
    {
        list.add(i,textList[i]);
    }

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listRow);
    listView.setAdapter(new setListView(list));
}

class setListView extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public setListView(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.text, list);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
        }

        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)row.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        RatingBarInfo rating;
        rating = (RatingBarInfo)ratingBar.getTag();
        if(rating == null)
        {
            rating = new RatingBarInfo(position);
            ratingBar.setTag(rating);
        }
        ratingBar.setRating(rating.getRating());

        TextView text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(list.get(position));

        return(row);
    }
}

class RatingBarInfo
{
    float rating;
    int position;

    public RatingBarInfo(int positionTemp)
    {
        rating = 2.0f;
        position = positionTemp;
    }

    public void setRating(float ratingTemp)
    {
        rating = ratingTemp;
    }

    public float getRating()
    {
        return rating;
    }

    public int getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }
}

public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,boolean fromUser) 
{
    RatingBarInfo ratingChange = (RatingBarInfo)ratingBar.getTag();
    ratingChange.setRating(rating);
    ratingBar.setTag(ratingChange);
    ((ArrayAdapter<String>)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set OnRatingBarChangeListener on your RatingBar.
Just add this line into your getView() method and it should works well.

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(MainActivity.this)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. That solved the problem. But now for some reason when I change the rating for one row another one also randomly changes. I'm wondering if this is because two different ratingbars are sharing the same tag?

Comment: Yes, it happens because two different list items can use the same view for displaying. Since you are storing rating bar value at the tag attached to the view, you have such bug. You can change your code and replace list of strings with list of your custom objects that hold its title and rating. This should fix the problem.

Comment: @VladimirMironov I have the same problem when I change the rating for one row another one also randomly changes. 

I did not get your point about "replace list of strings with list of your custom objects that hold its title and rating"

Can you please help?